# Universal arrows from an arbitrary set to the forgetful functor of pointed set

Tags: category-theory

So let us fix an arbitrary set $X\in$ **Set**, I want to find the universal arrow from $X$ to the forgetful functor $F:$ **Set$_*\rightarrow$** **Set**, where **Set$_*$** is the category of pointed sets.

By definition, I would want to produce an ordered pair $<\Omega, \phi>$,
$\phi:X \rightarrow F\Omega$,

such that for any given pair of $<\Theta, \psi>$, there is an unique (base-preserving) function $f : \Omega \rightarrow \Theta$ where $\psi = Ff\ \circ \phi$

So firstly I want to produce a pointed set $\Omega$ (that depends on $X$), I had tried to use AC to well order $X$ and choose the least element as my base, but this does not guarantee an unique $f$ between my $\Omega$ and another arbitrary pointed set $\Theta$.

So how to do go about producing the required ordered pair (the universal arrow)? Any hints or insight is deeply appreciated.

Cheers and thanks

Comment: You should simply add a point to $X$

Comment: @Max Thanks for the reply. But I do still want to clarify something. So basically you suggest I add a point to $X$, I would guess to serve as the base point and hence call the new set $\Omega$. How how do this ensure a unique $f$ to another arbitrary $\Theta$, besides base-point preservation, I don't have any control over other elements. Does'nt this means I could potentially have 2 different $f$ that preserve base-point, but disagree on some other elements ?

Comment: You do have control over other elements since you have $\psi$